# HTML set selection object to none for some elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection

I have a few elements on page which are selectable. 
To disable selection, I am using '-webkit-user-select' and setting it to none.

The problem arises when I select a selection-disabled element after selecting a selectable element.

```
window.getSelection() ---> returns the previously selected "selectable" element.
```

Is there a way to override this behaviour (preferably CSS), and set selection object to 'None' on selecting the selection-disabled element ?
I want to avoid using `removeAllRanges()`

Comment: if you can post jsfiddle it might helpfull

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fqdnhqjz/

Comment: If you select some text on the selectable line.. the span modifies the innerHTML accordingly. On clicking the select-disabled line, the span shows the earlier selection. Instead, selection must be emptied and selection object must be set at none, can this be achieved ?